# How to change password in Linux on Odroid

Tags: linux, password, embedded

I have Odroid and Linux on it. I have only these commands:

```
[                  hostname           mkfs_ext2          rmmod
[[                 hush               mknod              route
busybox            ifconfig           mount              sh
cat                inetd              mv                 sleep
chmod              init               netstat            stty
chown              insmod             nslookup           tail
cp                 kill               ntpd               telnetd
date               killall            odroid.sys.update  tftp
dd                 ln                 ping               traceroute
dmesg              login              ps                 umount
echo               ls                 pwd                vi
fsck.ext2          lsmod              reboot             wc  
ftpd               mkdir              rm                 wget
```

I have no password on `root` and I want to add a password to it. When Linux starts, it asks for a login and password? I can connect to my Odroid through ZOC, FAR manager (using NetBox) and Tftpd32. I need to add a password when I connect ZOC, FAR and TFTPD. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In busibox i turn on CONFIG PASSWD=yes also add this line in vg7.initramfs `slink /bin/passwd busybox 777 0 0`
 rebuild my vg7.img and kernel, start kernel and i can change my pussword with passwd command.